# sidekiq-status not autocalculating percentage for work done

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

I am using ***sidekiq-status gem*** to show a progress bar with a percentage of work completed. I followed [this](https://pramod-shinde.com/tag/sidekiq-status/) and [that](https://cclettenberg.com/ruby-on-rails/2016/02/20/display-progress-with-sidekiq-batches.html)

By using require ***sidekiq-status/web*** I could see "statuses" bar on /sidekiq interfaces. Problem is that at initial it shows *0% completed* and after finishing the whole task it displays *100% completed*.....I want it to display step by step percentages like 10%, 20%......100%

I did not use "at" method provided by sidekiq e.g. at 5, "Almost done"

Do I need to add at 10, at 20, at 30 to get the work done? Or it automatically calculates for us and displays it?

Comment: You need to use the `at` method, in different parts of your code.

Comment: Yes! that is the only solution. Thank you